# How to define a C++ concept for a range to a std::pair of reference wrappers?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

See the code below (also here https://www.godbolt.org/z/hvnvEv1ar).  The code fails to compile if I uncomment the constraint for either `rng` or `pair`.  I feel like I am missing something trivial, but I can't figure out why the constraint is not satisfied.

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct is_reference_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_reference_wrapper_v = is_reference_wrapper<T>::value;
template <typename T>
concept ReferenceWrapper = is_reference_wrapper_v<T>;
template <typename T>
concept ReferenceWrapperPair = requires(const T& t) {
    { t.first } -> ReferenceWrapper;
    { t.second } -> ReferenceWrapper;
};
template <typename T>
concept ReferenceWrapperPairRange =
    std::ranges::range<T> && ReferenceWrapperPair<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v{ {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };
    auto fn = [](std::pair<int, int>& val) {
        return std::pair{std::reference_wrapper<int>{val.first}, std::reference_wrapper<int>{val.second} };
    };
    /* ReferenceWrapperPairRange */ auto rng = v | std::views::transform(fn);
    /* ReferenceWrapperPair */ auto pair = *(rng.begin());
    ReferenceWrapper auto first = pair.first;
    ReferenceWrapper auto second = pair.second;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As expressions, `t.first` and `.second` must surely yield _actual_ references...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compound requirements `{ expression } -> type-constraint` requires that `decltype((expression))` must satisfy the constraints imposed by `type-constraint`, since `decltype((t.first))` will be treated as an ordinary lvalue expression, it will result in a const lvalue reference type.

You might want to use C++23 `auto(x)` to get the decay type

```
template <typename T>
concept ReferenceWrapperPair = requires(const T& t) {
    { auto(t.first) } -> ReferenceWrapper;
    { auto(t.second) } -> ReferenceWrapper;
};
```

Or change `ReferenceWrapper` concept to:

```
template <typename T>
concept ReferenceWrapper = is_reference_wrapper_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;
```

Comment: It most certainly is not a reference type. The issue is `decltype((t.first))` encoding value categories as reference types.

Comment: Oops, I shouldn't have answered so hastily as to be inaccurate, thanks for the correction.