# Concept that requires a certain return type of member

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have some trouble getting started with C++20 concepts. I want to define a concept that requires a class to have a member called `count_` that must be of type `int`:

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept HasCount = requires(T thing) {
    { thing.count_ } -> std::same_as<int>;
};
```

The following struct should satisfy this concept:

```
struct BaseTableChunk {
    BaseTableChunk* next_;
    int count_ = 0;
    int data_[1000];
};
```

Then, the following code does not compile:

```
template <HasCount Chunk>
class BaseTable {
    void doSomething();
};

int main() {
    BaseTable<BaseTableChunk> table{};
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/compare:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_pair.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from Minimal2.cxx:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/concepts:57:15:   required for the satisfaction of ‘__same_as<_Tp, _Up>’ [with _Tp = int&; _Up = int]
/usr/include/c++/10/concepts:62:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘same_as<int&, int>’
/usr/include/c++/10/concepts:57:32: note: the expression ‘is_same_v<_Tp, _Up> [with _Tp = int&; _Up = int]’ evaluated to ‘false’
   57 |       concept __same_as = std::is_same_v<_Tp, _Up>;
```

As I understand it, `thing.count_` is evaluated to return an `int&` instead of an `int`, which is not what I'd expect.

Should I instead test for `{ thing.count_ } -> std::same_as<int&>`? (Which then does compile.) That seems rather counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: *"Should I instead test for { thing.count_ } -> std::same_as<int&>? "*, if you do that, does it then compile?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951667/how-to-define-a-c-concept-for-a-range-to-a-stdpair-of-reference-wrappers/73951711#73951711

Comment: The thing to remember is that you are testing the type of an _expression_.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If `count_` is a member of `thing` with declared type `int`, then the expression `thing.count_` is also of type `int` and the expression's value category is *lvalue*.

A compound requirement of the form `{ E } -> C` will test whether `decltype((E))` satisfies `C`. In other words, it tests whether the type of the *expression* `E`, not the type of the entity that `E` might name, satisfies the concept.

The type of the expression as obtained by `decltype((E))` translates the value category to reference-qualification of the type. Prvalues result in non-references, lvalues in lvalue references and xvalues in rvalue references.

So, in your example, the type will be `int&` but the concept `std::same_as` requires strict match of the type, including its reference-qualification, making it fail.

---

A simple solution would be to just test against `int&`:

```
{ thing.count_ } -> std::same_as<int&>;
```

A similar solution as mentioned also in the question comments is since C++23:

```
{ auto(thing.count_) } -> std::same_as<int>
```

`auto` is deduced to `int` and the functional-style cast expression `int(...)` is always a prvalue, so that it will never result in a reference-qualified type.

Another alternative is to write a concept to replace `std::same_as` that doesn't check exact type equality but applies `std::remove_reference_t` or `std::remove_cvref_t` to the type first, depending on how you want to handle `const`-mismatch. Notably, the first solution will not accept a `const int` member or `const`-qualified `T` with `int` member, while the second one will (because `auto` never deduces a `const`).

---

However, you should be careful here if you intend to check that `thing` has a member of type `int` *exactly*. All of the solutions above will also be satisfied if it has a `thing` member of type reference-to-`int`.

Excluding the reference case cannot be done with a compound requirement easily, but a nested requirement may be used instead:

```
template <typename T>
concept HasCount = requires(T thing) {
    requires std::same_as<decltype(thing.count_), int>;
};
```

The nested requirement (introduced by another `requires`) checks not only validity of the expression but also whether it evaluates to `true`. The difference in the check here is that I use `decltype(thing.count_)` instead of `decltype((thing.count_))`. `decltype` has an exception when it names a member directly through a member access expression (unparenthesized). In that case it will produce the type of the named entity, not of the expression. This verifies that `count_` is a `int`, not a `int&`.

---

There are also further edge cases you should consider if `T` is `const`-qualified or a reference type. You should carefully consider under which conditions exactly the concept should be satisfied in these cases. Depending on the answer the suggested solutions may or may not be sufficient.

---

And as another edge case you need to consider whether you really want to accept *any* member or only non-`static` ones. All of the solutions above assume that you will accept a `static` member as well.

---

Also, you need to consider whether a member inherited from a base class should be accepted. All of the suggested solutions above do accept them.

---

All of the above solutions also assume that the member should be accepted only if it is `public`. The check in the concept is done from a context not related to any class, so accessibility based on context doesn't work anyway, and there probably is no reason to accept a `private` member that then wouldn't actually be usable in the function that is constrained by the concept.

Comment: "*Excluding the reference case cannot be done with a compound requirement easily*" Are there particular drawbacks or gotchas to `{ &T::count_ } -> std::same_as<int T::*>;`?

Comment: @ildjarn It won't accept static members, although it may very well be possible that OP only wants to match non-static members anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn Also, that won't accept members inherited from a base class. Again something that may or may not be desired.

Comment: Excellent answer. As an aside, what about member access restrictions (private/protected member)?

Comment: Excellenter I'd say